# How can i compress mjpeg native format frame from a webcam

Tags: c++, c, jpeg, raspberry-pi

I have written a server-client program in C (with socket).

1. The frames are:

   - captured in MJPEG native format 640x480 (the other native format is YUYV)
   - size of a single frame is 204000 Byte ( 200 KB )
2. The network is in ad-hoc mode so i get only 11-12 Mbps.
3. The purpose transmission speed : 25-30 fps (which obviously are not achieved).

So i need to compress the frames before sending, my question are:

```
1. what format could i use? 
2. I am making use of the API V4L2, so i want to know if there is a method, 
   function, etc. inside of this API that i can use for my purpose.
```

Comment: An MJPEG stream already is compressed, further attempts of compression might even make the data *bigger*. You might want to consider recoding the stream to something that compresses better.

Comment: you're right. I have only these 2 native format: MJPEG and YUYV(422), how can i proceed?

Comment: The MJPEG data is currently getting a compression ratio of about 4.5:1. This means the camera is compressing it with a very high quality setting. You can re-compress the data at a lower quality setting. At a compression ratio of 20:1, the quality is still decent. If you know that the images will not have characteristics which favor other types of compression (e.g. PNG - large areas of constant color), then a lower quality setting is probably the way to go. If you can't tell the camera what quality to use, then you'll need to recode the image.

Answer (score 0):

Check Multi-format video transport for IP/Ethernet
http://www.nevion.com/products/vs902/vs902
http://www.nevion.com/solutions/video-compression